# Is any classifier not subject (or less susceptible) to fooling?

Tags: machine-learning, models, adversarial-ml, model-request

Is any classifier not subject to fooling as in [here](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Nguyen_Deep_Neural_Networks_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf)?

My question is related to [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/6892/2444), but not an exact duplicate.

What I wanted to ask is that any classifiers inherently do not subject (or less prone) to attack. I have a feeling that non-linear classifiers should be less susceptible to attack.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is not necessarily a duplicate but quite similar to some other questions. However, I will answer the question posed here.

At a theoretical level, what you are asking is there any algorithm that cannot be tricked into predicting the wrong class?

The answer is: **No**

It is analogous to asking whether there is a perfect architecture for an arbitrary classification problem, and that answer is quite obviously not. It would also not likely to be terribly difficult to show this is provably the case, at least for a class of algorithms(i.e connectionist models).